# Как сделать границы произвольной формы?

Tags: html, css

[image: Блок]

Задался вопросом, как можно реализовать блок такой формы, чтобы сделать такие границы? И вообще как можно сделать непрямоугольный блок?

Comment: Пост на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/

Comment: Я бы просто нарисовал картинку и поставил её на фон

Comment: Если говорить о примере на вашем изображении, то тут можно обойтись свойством `transform: skewX(-Ndeg);`. Получим примерно [такой результат](https://jsfiddle.net/so15htnr/)

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен блок формы отличной от прямоугольника и квадрата с зоной выделения то тут нужно применение svg. Если же зона выделения значения не имеет - то предложенные варианты в комментариях сгодятся.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию [skew](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew). Решение вашего вопроса - https://codepen.io/Grishko/pen/qpxXXm

```
<div class="skew"><span>Текст</span></div>

.skew {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
}
.skew span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skew(10deg);
}
```